# Why are 2 rows affected in my `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update

I'm doing an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for a `PRIMARY KEY` in the following table:

```
DESCRIBE users_interests;
```

```
+------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid        | int(11)                         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| iid        | int(11)                         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| preference | enum('like','dislike','ignore') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

However, even though these values should be unique, I'm seeing 2 rows affected.

```
INSERT INTO users_interests (uid, iid, preference) VALUES (2, 2, 'like')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE preference='like';
```

```
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

For comparison, see this query:

```
UPDATE users_interests SET preference='like' WHERE uid=2 AND iid=2;
```

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.44 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Why do you have two primary keys in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka, the `PRIMARY KEY` is a single pk created on `(uid, iid)` since most queries will be run when both values are known.

Comment: @Josh I see. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) seems to discourage it though: `In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.` Does it need to be a primary key? Why not a normal index?

Comment: @Pekka, honestly not sure. I'm still relatively new to this. Does an index make more sense in this case?

Comment: @Josh yup, a normal index spanning both columns should would work fine here

Comment: Pekka - To me he appears to be saying that there is indeed only one index, across both columns. (AFAIK MySQL won't allow you to declare two primary keys anyway.)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the
>   affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row and 2
>   if an existing row is updated.

Comment: And 0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

Comment: I just wonder what would be the rationale behind it.. clearly, it could have been returned as response code instead of number of rows affected to make it less confusing

Comment: ... :|. Is there a way to determine the _actual_ number of rows affected? Even if an existing row is updated, there is still only _one_ row affected

Comment: Is this the same for batch inserts as well? `… VALUES (2, 2, 'like'), (3, 3, 'like'), (4, 4, 'like')
ON DUPLICATE …`

Comment: I wonder how many like me wasted 30 minutes trying to figure out WHICH two rows were updated...only to discover this arcane abuse of an interface.

Comment: @Svish and on the same paragraph in the doc, there's a flag `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` that makes such case return 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 9):

So you know whether you updated a row (duplicate key) or just inserted one: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html