# MySQL insert row on duplicate key update multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table `(name, date, stat1, stat2, stat3)`, `(name, date)` is the PK. When I insert rows, there will be duplicate keys, and I need to sum up the three stats. I use the following query with PreparedStatement in Java:

```
INSERT INTO tb (name, date, stat1, stat2, stat3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stat1 = stat1 + ?, stat2 = stat2 + ?, stat3 = stat3 + ?
```

Is there a more concise query to achieve that? Because I have simplify the query, there are over ten stats there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tb (name, date, stat1, stat2, stat3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stat1 = stat1 + VALUES(stat1), stat2 = stat2 + VALUES(stat2), stat3 = stat3 + VALUES(stat3)
```

Comment: It is better. But is it possible that I don't need to repeat every stat?

Comment: I see this is an old question, but another option is writing a procedure with the stats in a string and then looping through them (after splitting). May not be less code but it will be more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Add a computed column (sum) and include that in your PK.

However, this does denormalize your table. You could use a surrogate key and do the calculation in your SELECT

Answer (score -3):

If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row. For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two statements have similar effect:

> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

The equivalent update query is as below,

> UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;

If a and b column is unique, equivalent update query would be ,

> UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1 OR b=2 LIMIT 1;

Comment: You've already posted the same answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672203/insert-or-if-column-combination-exists-update/20674595#20674595). If you feel this question is similar, flag it as a duplicate instead.