# INSERT or if column combination exists UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a user-meta-data table where I store some additional values. I need to:

A) INSERT a new user_id/meta_type combination + value

OR

B) if there already is the user_id/meta_type combination then just update its value

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

I found MySQL's "`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`" - but from what I understood from the manual it seems like it only checks for a `PRIMARY KEY` so the question is:

A) Is there a way to do something like "ON DUPLICATE COLUMN1 AND COLUMN2 UPDATE value"?

B) Is it possible in MySQL InnoDB to create `PRIMARY KEY` on multiple columns? 
   
    (e.g. meta_id+user_id+meta_type would be the `PRIMARY KEY`)

C) Did I understand the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` manual wrong?

Comment: No, it doesn't check for a primary key. Any unique index will work.

Comment: And you can certainly have a unique index on multiple columns.

Comment: Yes on B though. You can have composite primary keys. `CREATE TABLE t (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (a, b))`

Comment: Yes, you can create a composite primary key, but you could also just create a `UNIQUE` composite index on those columns `ALTER TABLE t ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_meta_id_user_id_meta_type (meta_id, user_id, meta_type)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That should be `ADD UNIQUE INDEX ...`

Comment: @Barmar Messed up and had to retype it, meanwhile missed `UNIQUE`, thanks.

Comment: Why not you can do it with 2 calls from php to mysql?

Comment: I solved it with your help - SO - **are any of you guys going to compose an answer** containing BOTH - the alter table + the ON DUPLICATE statement usage ? @IgnacioOcampo because the number of meta values may vary... And I want to avoid any additional DB calls, but its a good point...

Answer (score 0):

If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row. For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two statements have similar effect:

> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

The equivalent update query is as below,

> UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;

If a and b column is unique, equivalent update query would be ,

> UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1 OR b=2 LIMIT 1;