# How update only null values during "insert on duplicate key update" with Hibernate and MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-customsql) is custom insert sql statement example for overriding default hibernate template. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913509/1251549) is example of using update on duplicate key found. Is there a way to skip null values during update on duplicate? I mean that if entity already exists, it is need to update only null values. Can this situation be handled by custom @SQLInsert annotation in hibernate?

Comment: You could use an IF-statement. Something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field = IF(field = null, VALUES(field), field)`