# Hibernate @SqlInsert annotation getting nulls from bean and not values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to insert into a mysql table using jpa + hibernate and @SQLInsert annotation. (I was trying a more elaborate insert query until I realized the basic one isn't working). The bean is below, what is happening in on entityManager.persist (or entityManager.merge), even though I set the 3 values on the bean, and log them hibernate complains that CKEY is NULL

the bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert;

@Entity ( )
@Table ( name = "cachedb" )
@SQLInsert( sql="insert into cachedb ( ckey , cvalue , expiry ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ?  )")
public class CacheDb implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id ( )
    @Column ( name = "ckey" )
    private String key;

    @Column ( name = "cvalue" )
    private String value;

    @Column ( name = "expiry" )
    private Calendar expiry;

    @SuppressWarnings ( "unused" )
    private CacheDb()
    {
    }

    public CacheDb( final String _key , final String _value )
    {
        this.key = _key;
        this.value = _value;
    }

    public CacheDb( final String _key , final String _value , final int expirtyMinutes )
    {
        this.key = _key;
        this.value = _value;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add( Calendar.MINUTE , expirtyMinutes );
        this.expiry = cal;
    }

    public Calendar getExpiry()
    {
        return this.expiry;
    }

    public void setExpiry( final Calendar _expiry )
    {
        this.expiry = _expiry;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid()
    {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public void setKey( final String _key )
    {
        this.key = _key;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return this.key;
    }

    public void setIKey( final String _key )
    {
        this.key = _key;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue( final String _value )
    {
        this.value = _value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "CacheDb [key=" + this.key + ", value=" + this.value + ", expiry=" + this.expiry + "]";
    }
}
```

some sample code I use to test inserts:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import com.database.jpa.EntityUtils;

public class TestInsert
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {      
        javax.persistence.EntityManager em = null;
        String key = "KEY.TEST.08082017";
        try        
        {
            em = EntityUtils.getEntityManagerWithOutTransaction( "RLENTYMGR" );
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            final Query q = em.createQuery("select p from CacheDb p where key = ?1" );
            q.setParameter( 1 , key );
            final List<CacheDb> resultsList = q.getResultList();
            if (resultsList.size()==0)
            {
                CacheDb newRecord = new CacheDb();
                newRecord.setKey( key ); // only required column varchar(100)
                newRecord.setValue( "TESTB" ); //varchar(1000)   
                //newRecord.setExpiry(null); not needed default is null                 
                em.persist( newRecord );
                //newRecord = em.merge( newRecord );
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (em!=null) 
            {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (em!=null) {em.close();}
        }
    }




}
```

the exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'CKEY' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:123)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that hibernate doesn't look at the order of columns you use in `@SQLInsert`.

It only uses its own order—which you have to find out first by letting Hibernate generate an insert statment for you and then mimicking it in your custom `@SQLInsert`.

Answer (score 3):

As @user1889665 [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577643/6346531), hibernate uses its own ordering of columns, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-custom-crud-example):

> The parameter order is important and is defined by the order Hibernate handles properties. You can see the expected order by enabling debug logging, so Hibernate can print out the static SQL that is used to create, update, delete entities.
>
> To see the expected sequence, remember to not include your custom SQL through annotations or mapping files as that will override the Hibernate generated static SQL.

Basically, you need to do this:

- Remove `@SQLInsert`
- Enable debug logging

  ```
  logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
  ```
- Insert entity normally

  ```java
  myCrudRepository.save(myEntity)
  ```
- Check logs to see the insert statement generated

  ```
  org.hibernate.SQL : insert into MY_TABLE (notMyFirstColumn, myLastColumn, myFirstColumn) values (?, ?, ?)
  ```
- Use the order from insert statement printed in logs in `@SQLInsert`

  ```java
  @SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(notMyFirstColumn, myLastColumn, myFirstColumn) values (?, ?, ?)")
  ```