# Increase quantity in duplicate insertion jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have use case in JPA where I need to increase the quantity or update the existing row with quantity on duplicate insertion of a primary key.

`````
@Table(name = "order_line_exception")
@IdClass(OrderLineExceptionKey.class)
public class OrderLineException

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private long orderId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "gtin_nbr")
    private String gtinNbr;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_line_nbr")
    private short orderLineNbr;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "exception_code")
    private short exceptionCode;

    @Column(name = "exception_qty")
    private int exceptionQty;
}````

increase exceptionQty if same primary key repeated
`````

Comment: So you're assuming your primary key will be duplicated - that's impossible.

Comment: @Andronicus That impossible in the database, but it doesn't mean that someone cannot still try to _attempt_ that insert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Hibernate work with MySQL's "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913341/can-hibernate-work-with-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update-syntax)

Comment: Ach ok, maybe I misunderstood. That entity doesn't have to be written to the database, only one field incremented, right?

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen I am looking for similar type of requirement but can be controlled on repository.save(entity) and not always +1 it should exceptionQty = existingexceptionQty + newexceptionQty

Comment: This is business logic and should be implemented and testes by your application business code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/INSERT#insert-object), combined with [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/UPSERT#postgresql) clause.